# IPREV check failing on multiple ipv6 addresses

Tags: postfix, ip, dovecot, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 5b running Ubuntu to host a Postfix and Dovecot mailserver from my home. After setting up various sender authentication mechanisms on the server eg. SPF, DKIM and DMARC - and checking these by mailing `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` which verifies these checks for you; I realised my reverse IP lookup iprev check is failing. This is because I don't know how to implement the correct ptr record for the range of sender IP addresses my server likes to use.

Some mail is sent using my home network's ipv4 (we'll call this `62.148.221.203`)
However, some mail is sent using various ipv6 addresses covered by this IP and subnet (we'll call this `4d11:76h7:98l1:44g6::/64`).

My domain `example.com` is hosted with Google Domains, so I have access to add and amend my own PTR records. The mailserver is at `mail.example.com`. What I'm after is a PTR record which allows the iprev check to pass when mail has been sent from EITHER my ipv4, or any of the ipv6 addresses under that address and subnet.

On Gdomains I have the columns **HOSTNAME** which appends `.example.com` after the input into the box, **TYPE** (PTR), **TTL** (default 1hr) and finally **DATA**.

Using the example IP's I've provided; what is the record going to look like? I've done plenty of research and I really can't find a way to authenticate both the ipv4 and all possible ipv6 addresses it can use.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you want to read up on *what* and *where* PTR records are. The case where they are set up with the same party as your `.com` domain name is rare.